# bootstrap custom css navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got this thing in common condition,
but the thing is I am a new guy and now I learn how to create HTML with bootstrap to "typing less"

This is the case I just get, I create my own navigation with `UL` `Li` tags and I want a responsive one with bootstrap, first thought it just simple to using bootstrap responsive by inputting the ID from bootstrap and toggle, but it's not.

Please somebody tell me where should I begin to learn bootstrap and modifying things and what is so wrong with my code, I think it's good to join bootstrap to my code

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.navigation {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.navigation-modified ul,
li,
ol {
  margin: 0;
  font: #000;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.navigation-modified li {
  border: 2px solid red;
  min-width: 200px;
  padding: 5px 30px;
}
.navigation-modified li:nth-child(n+2) {
  margin-left: -2px;
}
.navigation-modified li:hover {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />

  <title>Test2</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <nav id="navbarCollapse" class="navigation navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navigation-modified">
        <a href="#">
          <li>Home</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Registration</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Tutorial</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Contact Us</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

**Note**: I don't put bootstrap CSS and JS, it's too long. Please run on your local using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.........

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

      <title>Test2</title>
      <style>
      body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .navigation-modified
    {
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }
    .navigation {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0;
      margin-top: 15px;
    }
    .navigation-modified ul,
    li,
    ol {
      margin: 0;
      font: #000;
      list-style: none;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .navigation-modified li {
      border: 2px solid red;
      min-width: 200px;
      padding: 5px 30px;
    }
    .navigation-modified li:nth-child(n+2) {
      margin-left: -2px;
    }
    .navigation-modified li:hover {
      padding: 10px 40px;
      margin-top: -15px;
    }
    </style>    
    </head>

    <body>
      <header>  
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="navigation-modified">
            <a href="#">
              <li>Home</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Registration</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Tutorial</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Contact Us</li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

       </header>

    </body>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </html>
```